# How to fire a resize event?

Tags: java, gwt

I tried this code below which seems perfectly fine, but it gives me errors on `handler.onResize(this)` and tell me:

> The method onResize(ResizeEvent) in the type ResizeHandler is not applicable for the arguments (new GwtEvent(){})

Here's my code:

```
private void update(){
    this.fireEvent(new GwtEvent<ResizeHandler>(){

        @Override
        public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<ResizeHandler> getAssociatedType() {
            return new Type<ResizeHandler>();
        }

        @Override
        protected void dispatch(ResizeHandler handler) {
            handler.onResize(this);
        }

        });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass in a [`new ResizeEvent()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ResizeEvent.html) and override the methods you need? `ResizeHandler.onResize` takes a ResizeEvent, not a GwtEvent.

Comment: Oh it works! I forgot the curly braces so eclipse did not auto complete so I thought it was not working... Can you make an answer so I can select it?

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in a [`new ResizeEvent()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ResizeEvent.html) and override the methods you need. ResizeHandler's `onResize` takes a `ResizeEvent`, not a `GwtEvent`.